# How to correctly wait until JavaScript applies inline Css

Tags: javascript, css

I have this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haruosoft/ZLPAX/). When the button is clicked, I want to put the red div behind the black one immediately, then start the animation.

```
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click",function () {
    red.style.zIndex = -1;
    red.classList.remove("shifted");
});
```

However, as you can see, they seem to be occurring as two separate actions. I know I can use `setTimeout` to wait until the zIndex property is applied, but I do not know how long I am supposed to wait, and the duration perhaps differs from browsers to computers.

Should I create a loop that will check if zindex was applied? But this also sounds like an unintelligent solution. What is the correct way?

EDIT: I do not want to change the zIndex on the black div.

Comment: you can safely wait zero ms in a setTimeout for the change to take effect.

Comment: That did not work. Maybe I am doing it incorrectly. Can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a

```
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
```

into the `#red` and everything is fine. ;) This applies the `transition` only to specified property.

## **JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qvh7G/.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind to the transitioned state of the element, something like this:

```
("#mySelector").bind("transitionend", function(){ 'yourcodehere' });
```

Also, here is some info on it:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend

Without jQuery:

```
el.addEventListener("transitionend", updateTransition, true);
```

Edit:

There was some confusion as to the usage of:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
```

This is applied like a styling as well. So anytime you make alterations to the element it is on, you are triggering this. You have TWO transition calls, one for setting the z-index, another for the movement.

Comment: You may want to point out that your answer requires jQuery, which the questions isn't tagged with.

Comment: No problem, added the example from the mozilla site. I highly suggest reading it to get a better understanding of the callback function if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm a little confused here....what does `transitionend` have to do with changing a z-index?

Comment: @m59 It has to do with the transition that is used.

Comment: @feeela I know exactly what `transitionend` does.. it seems irrelevant to the question. He's not trying to do something after the transition. He's trying to do something before it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this probably does not work as I want to hide the div first, then perform the transition.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle, when you click hide, you start a transition to hide the red div. So at the end of that, then trigger the next transition.

I think it might be possible you just want to set #red to z-index -1 to start with, which could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, *transitionend* support is only available in fairly recent browsers so ensure there is a suitable fallback.

Comment: @Organiccat, I am still a little confused. Why would I have the next transition? I have only one. Regarding #red to z-index -1, I can't do that because the z-index on the red div must be greater than the black's at the start of the animation.

Comment: No, you have two, you set -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; on your #red element, so anytime you alter that element, it will take 1 second. So setting z-index takes 1 second, so does the movement.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I need to wait for the z-index to apply for 1s, then perform the animation which takes another 1s? I'd like the z-index to apply immediately if possible.

Comment: Put the z-index on `#black`.

Comment: You'll have to set your transition to 0 (or start with zero), then do your z-index, then set your transition back to 1s.

Comment: @Organiccat But both (z-index and remove) will still happen at same time?

Comment: It won't matter at that point, the z-index will change first (instantly) and then the transition will happen. Since the z-index instantly changes, the user won't notice.

Comment: But, arrgh, confused, how do you apply a higher `transition-duration`, wich is first `0`, to the already at the same time removed class?

Comment: Ok, I am on the way to it, is the changing of the `transition-duration` also a transition? ;)

Comment: @Galchen posted a comment, which pointed into right direction, could not implement 1:1, was deleted then, but this is the outcome: http://jsfiddle.net/Qvh7G/ !! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with zIndex - the transform time delays the change in the zIndex.

You can simply force the duration for the `transform` property.

Replace:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
```

With

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s; // ease-in;
```

Comment: I tried this, but there is a significant delay between a button click and the start of the animation.

Comment: You want the div to resize, and as soon as it's done - change it to black ?

Comment: There is no resizing or change of color. Just z-index update and animation.

Comment: ahh, the problem is with the zIndex - it's not instant due to the transition

Comment: I like this, although it is not exactly what I wanted because this simply delays the animation by using `ease-in`. But it looks like it works!

Comment: remove the ease-in then

Comment: BTW, even with ease-in, the transition is not delayed, it starts immediately, just slow. You can simply remove the `ease-in`